# Prefetching indirectly related items using Django ORM

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-orm

I'm trying to optimize the queries for my moderation system, build with Django and DRF.
I'm currently stuck with the duplicates retrieval: currently, I have something like

```py
class AdminSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    duplicates = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_duplicates(self, item):
        if item.allowed:
            qs = []
        else:
            qs = Item.objects.filter(
                    allowed=True, 
                    related_stuff__language=item.related_stuff.language
                ).annotate(
                    similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', item.name)
                ).filter(similarity__gt=0.2).order_by('-similarity')[:10]
    return AdminMinimalSerializer(qs, many=True).data
```

which works fine, but does at least one additional query for each item to display. In addition, if there are duplicates, I'll do additional queries to fill the `AdminMinimalSerializer`, which contains fields and related objects of the duplicated item. I can probably reduce the overhead by using a `prefetch_related` inside the serializer, but that doesn't prevent me from making several queries per item (assuming I have only one related item to prefetch in `AdminMinimalSerializer`, I'd still have ~2N + 1 queries: 1 for the items, N for the duplicates, N for the related items of the duplicates).

I've already looked at `Subquery`, but I can't retrieve an object, only an id, and this is not enough in my case. I tried to use it in both a `Prefetch` object and a `.annotate`.

I also tried something like `Item.filter(allowed=False).prefetch(Prefetch("related_stuff__language__related_stuff_set__items", queryset=Items.filter..., to_attr="duplicates"))`, but the `duplicates` property is added to "related_stuff__language__related_stuff_set", so I can't really use it...

I'll welcome any idea ;)

**Edit:** the real code lives [here](https://gitlab.begel.fr/guillaume/lecturaddicts_server/blob/dev/books/). Toy example below:

```py
# models.py
from django.db.models import Model, CharField, ForeignKey, CASCADE, BooleanField

class Book(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=250)
    serie = ForeignKey(Serie, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="books")
    allowed = BooleanField(default=False)

class Serie(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=250)
    language = ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="series")

class Language(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
```

```py
# serializers.py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, SerializerMethodField

from .models import Book, Language, Serie

class BookAdminSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("id", "title", "serie", "duplicates", )

    serie = SerieAdminAuxSerializer()
    duplicates = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_duplicates(self, book):
        """Retrieve duplicates for book"""
        if book.allowed:
            qs = []
        else:
            qs = (
                Book.objects.filter(
                    allowed=True, serie__language=book.serie.language)
                .annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity("title", book.title))
                .filter(similarity__gt=0.2)
                .order_by("-similarity")[:10]
            )
        return BookAdminMinimalSerializer(qs, many=True).data


class BookAdminMinimalSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ("id", "title", "serie")

    serie = SerieAdminAuxSerializer()

class SerieAdminAuxSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Serie
        fields = ("id", "language", "title")

    language = LanguageSerializer()

class LanguageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

I'm trying to find a way to prefetch related objects and duplicates so that I can get rid of the `get_duplicates` method in `BookSerializer`, with the N+1 queries it causes, and have only a `duplicates` field in my `BookSerializer`.

Regarding data, here would be an expected output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "test2",
        "serie": {
            "id": 2,
            "language": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "English"
            },
            "title": "series title"
        },
        "duplicates": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "test",
                "serie": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "language": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "English"
                    },
                    "title": "first series title"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "random",
        "serie": {
            "id": 3,
            "language": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "English"
            },
            "title": "random series title"
        },
        "duplicates": []
    }
]
```